# How to read CSV files with umlaut in the file name?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, oledb, jet

Using JET OleDB, how can I read a CSV file which has umlauts in the filename?

The following example tries to read two different csv files (böse.csv and good.csv). The content of both files is the same, but the filenames are different.

First a schema.ini file is set up for both files:

```
    private static readonly string[] columns = {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"};
const string workingFolder = "D:\\temp\\";
const string bad = "böse.csv";
const string good = "good.csv";

private static void CreateSchemaIni()
{
    StreamWriter iniOut = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(workingFolder, "schema.ini"), false);
    iniOut.WriteLine("[" + bad + "]");
    iniOut.WriteLine("Format=Delimited(;)");
    iniOut.WriteLine("CharacterSet=65001"); // hidden feature: setzen der Codepage auf UTF-8
    for (int columnId = 0; columnId < columns.Length; columnId++)
    {
        // Memo statt Text, damit bei 255 Zeichen nicht abgeschnitten wird
        iniOut.WriteLine($"Col{columnId + 1}={columns[columnId]} Memo");
    }
    iniOut.WriteLine("[" + good + "]");
    iniOut.WriteLine("Format=Delimited(;)");
    iniOut.WriteLine("CharacterSet=65001"); // hidden feature: setzen der Codepage auf UTF-8
    for (int columnId = 0; columnId < columns.Length; columnId++)
    {
        // Memo statt Text, damit bei 255 Zeichen nicht abgeschnitten wird
        iniOut.WriteLine($"Col{columnId + 1}={columns[columnId]} Memo");
    }
    iniOut.Close();
}
```

Once the schema has been created the csv files can be read using JET OleDB, simply the correct filename has to be placed in the connection string:

```
    const string connectionString =
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
    private static DataTable ReadCsv(string fileName)
    {
        string connString = string.Format(connectionString, workingFolder);
        string cmdString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", fileName);

        DataSet dataSet;
        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdString, connString))
        {
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }

        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

I would expect that the table for both files contains the same data, but it does not. "bad.csv" returns a table with only 1 column, reading "good.csv" returns a table with the expected 4 columns.

```
    private static void Dump(DataTable table)
    {
        int rowId = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Row {rowId++}:");
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{column.ColumnName}={row[column]}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Output for böse.csv:

```
Row 0:
        Column1; Column2; Column3; Column4 = 1; 2; 3; 4
Row 1:
        Column1; Column2; Column3; Column4 = 5; 6; 7; 8
```

Output for good.csv:

```
Row0:
        Column1 = 1
        Column2 = 2
        Column3 = 3
        Column4 = 4
Row1:
        Column1 = 5
        Column2 = 6
        Column3 = 7
        Column4 = 8
```

Is it possible in any way to read csv file with umlauts as expected?

Comment: rename the 2 files inverting the names (böse.csv -> good.csv and good.csv -> böse.csv) and repeat the test. you get the same result? after renaming the file with umulaut (the one previously 'good') is crippled?

Comment: It's not the content of the file making problems, it's the name of the file. So when changing the names, yes, the same result appears, but the content is not crippled.